# What is the recommended way to share a netty ByteBuf in multiple CompositeByteBuf instances?

Tags: java, netty

I wrote a couple of ByteBuf aggregators, I use them to handle two cases:

- Extracting content that is enclosed in header + tail wrappers
- Aggregating to same-sized ByteBuf instances

Both of these make use of CompositeByteBufs to allow for zero-copies, and may be composed.

I am not running this aggregators in a Netty pipeline since I do not know before-hand which transformation to apply.

With these two aggregators, a common case occurs; the view I create spans several ByteBuf instances and often does not end-up on clean ByteBuf boundaries.

I naively thought that I could derive two slices of the initial ByteBuf and then provision them in the respective CompositeByteBuf that are created to hold views. Unfortunately that is not the case, since as the documentation mentions, a CompositeByteBuf takes over refcount ownership of the underlying ByteBuf. Sometimes the underlying ByteBuf is freed as soon as CompositeByteBuf.addComponent() is called.

My question is then: is there a preferred way to do this? Right now I am calling Unpooled.copiedBuffer() on the tail that is to be reused to avoid the problem above, but was wondering if true zero-copy could be achieved and if so, what the recommended way would be.

Comment: maybe I missunderstand you but why you can just call `retain()` before you add it to the `CompositeByteBuf` ?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but It seemed as though the `release()` issued by the `CompositeByteBuf` was not automatic always happening. I circumvented it by systematically calling `retain()` before insertion and issuing a final `release()` once parsing is finished.